# SHCONN AT Command fails on SIMCOM 7080G

Tags: modem

My SIMCOM is a 7080G with las Firmware updated to:
APRev:1951B16SIM7080,B16V01
QCN:SIM7080G_P1.03_20201226
IMEI:860016041830931

I follow exactly the HTTP procedure described in:
SIM7070_SIM7080_SIM7090 Series_HTTP(S)_Application Note_V1.02

Everything is correct for the setup, IP is correct, carrier and PDP connection is fine.
When the system issued AT+SHCONN it always gives ERROR.

Tested with different SIMs
With different caller RxTx software.
One is C++ of myself, trivial,
Second is ATCommandTester utility

I will attach a log.

Thanks in advance,
And kind regards,
Horacio

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2023.11.08 20:29:17 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
SIMCOM 7080G AT CMD Test -> SendDataV6-em-7080-328
AT+CPIN?
AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY

OK

Debug
AT+CSQ
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 15,99

OK

Debug
AT+CGATT?
AT+CGATT?

+CGATT: 1

OK

Debug
AT+COPS?
AT+COPS?

+COPS: 0,0,"Claro AR",7

OK

Debug
AT+CGNAPN
AT+CGNAPN

+CGNAPN: 1,"em"

OK

Debug
AT+CNCFG=0,1,"em"
AT+CNCFG=0,1,"em"

OK

Debug
AT+CNACT=0,1
AT+CNACT=0,1

OK

+APP PDP: 0,ACTIVE

Debug
AT+CNACT?
AT+CNACT?

+CNACT: 0,1,"10.189.69.227"
+CNACT: 1,0,"0.0.0.0"
Debug
AT+CSQ
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 14,99

OK

Debug
4G HTTP Setup End!
AT+SHCONF="URL","http://nutritronix.com/selectV201W.php"
AT+SHCONF="URL","http://nutritronix.com/selectV201W.php"

OK

Debug
AT+SHCONF="BODYLEN",1024
AT+SHCONF="BODYLEN",1024

OK

Debug
AT+SHCONF="HEADERLEN",350
AT+SHCONF="HEADERLEN",350

OK

Debug
AT+SHCONN
AT+SHCONN

ERROR

Debug
AT+SHSTATE?
AT+SHSTATE?

+SHSTATE: 0

OK

Debug
AT+SHCHEAD
AT+SHCHEAD

ERROR

Debug
AT+SHAHEAD="Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
AT+SHAHEAD="Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Debug
AT+SHAHEAD="Cache-control","no-cache"
AT+SHAHEAD="Cache-control","no-cache"

ERROR

Debug
AT+SHAHEAD="Connection","keep-alive"
AT+SHAHEAD="Connection","keep-alive"

ERROR

Debug
AT+SHAHEAD="Accept","*/*"
AT+SHAHEAD="Accept","*/*"

ERROR

Debug
AT+SHBOD=40,10000>api_key=tPmAT5Ab3j7F9&device#=BC94
AT+SHBOD=40,10000>api_key=tPmAT5Ab3j7F9&device#=BC94

ERROR

Debug
AT+SHREQ="/post",3
AT+SHREQ="/post",3

ERROR

Debug
AT+SHREAD=0,38
AT+SHREAD=0,38

ERROR

Debug
AT+SHDISC
AT+SHDISC

ERROR
```

Comment: Try to enable extended error reporting to get more than just `ERROR` with `AT+CMEE=2`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disconnecting any previous http(s) instance with 'AT+SHDISC' before setting up the new instance?